# Calculation complex mathematical expressions in smartpy like ln, log, etc

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I want to calculate complex mathematical expressions such as `ln(94)` in smartpy.
How can this be done?

Comment: What is your usecase? The short answer is you can compute the ln (or any standard function) approximately, to any desired error bound, using polynomials (e.g. from a series expansion of the function, see Taylor models). The longer answer is that depending on your use case, maybe you can get away with not computing it, as is done in Defi with the square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple example for log₂ in [calculator.py](https://smartpy.io/ide?template=calculator.py).

```
    @sp.entrypoint
    def log2(self, x):
        self.data.result = 0
        y = x
        while y > 1:
            self.data.result += 1
            y /= 2
```

A faster and fixed precision version is shown in [fixed_precision.py](https://smartpy.io/ide?template=fixed_precision.py) for log₂.

```
# Fixed precision computations - Example for illustrative purposes only.

import smartpy as sp


"""
This has been inspired by

https://github.com/Sophia-Gold/michelson/blob/master/log2fix.tz

http://www.claysturner.com/dsp/BinaryLogarithm.pdf

1) Initialize result to 0: y = 0.
2) Initialize mantissa-bit decimal value to 0.5: b = 1/2.

3) While x < 1, x = 2x, y = y - 1.
4) While x >= 2, x = x/2, y = y + 1.

6) Square: x = x * x.
7) If x > 2, x = x/2, y = y + b.
8) Scale for next bit: b = b/2.
9) Go to Step 6 and repeat until desired number of mantissa bits are found.

10) Final log(x) value: y.
"""

@sp.module
def main():
    class MyContract(sp.Contract):
        def __init__(self, precision):
            self.private.precision = sp.cast(precision, sp.nat)
            self.data.value = 0

        @sp.entrypoint
        def log(self, params):
            assert params != 0
            y = 0
            x = params
            while x < 1 << self.private.precision:
                x <<= 1
                y -= sp.to_int(1 << self.private.precision)
            while x >= 2 << self.private.precision:
                x >>= 1
                y += sp.to_int(1 << self.private.precision)
            b = 1 << sp.as_nat(self.private.precision - 1)
            while 0 < b:
                x = (x * x) >> self.private.precision
                if x > 2 << self.private.precision:
                    x >>= 1
                    y += sp.to_int(b)
                b >>= 1
            self.data.value = y

def direct(x, precision):
    import math
    return int((math.log(x / (1 << precision)) / math.log(2)) * (1 << precision))

@sp.add_test(name = "FixedPrecision")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario(main)
    scenario.h1("Fixed Precision Computations")
    c1 = main.MyContract(precision = 16)
    scenario += c1
    def check_ok(scenario, n):
        d = direct(n, 16)
        scenario.h3("Computing log(%i / 65536)" % n)
        scenario.p("Direct computation %i" % direct(n, 16))
        c1.log(n)
        scenario.verify(abs(c1.data.value - d) < 2)
    check_ok(scenario, 1000000)
    check_ok(scenario, 65535)
    check_ok(scenario, 65536)
    check_ok(scenario, 65537)
    check_ok(scenario, 131071)
    check_ok(scenario, 131072)
    check_ok(scenario, 131073)
    check_ok(scenario, 1)
```